# How do I create permanent placeholders? CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, placeholder, contact-form-7

I am working on a web form for my first official development job.

I am currently trying to make it so that my input fields placeholders don't disappear but instead i need them to shrink and move to the top of the input field. 
I was able to find some code that should be getting the job done but is not.
Can anyone guide me on how to make this work?

Code I found: https://jsfiddle.net/p19j2nm5/

I've worked on this for hours trying all sorts of variations with no luck.

```
.wrapper /*wpcf7*/{
    position:relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;

}

.placeholder{
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  pointer-events:none;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus ~ .placeholder{
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

HTML from contact form 7:

```
<label> First Name:
[text first-name placeholder "First Name"] </label>


<label> Last Name:
    [text* last-name placeholder "Last Name"] </label>


<label> Your Email:
    [email* your-email placeholder "Example@Example.com"] </label>
```

Currently, none on my fields placeholders move when focused, but removing "~.placeholder" does make the field shrink when focused.

Example of what I am trying to get my fields to do: [image: the screenshot]

Comment: o not use a span put a label associated to your input via the for attribute : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label , the rest is a matter os style . https://jsfiddle.net/oxug56c4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input:focus ~ .lastname_floating-label,
input:focus ~ .firstname_floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .firstname_floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .lastname_floating-label{
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.firstname_floating-label, .lastname_floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
div{position:relative;}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
  <span class="firstname_floating-label">Firstname</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
  <span class="lastname_floating-label">Lastname</span>
</div>
```

Ok I changed according your request. 
Other examples are wrong. Try to add more input and you can check that the place holder will be positioned in the first input. And than if you focus out the placeholder will cover the typed value.

Check this example if is ok using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry, It is quiet confusing but here is an example I should have posted in the original post: https://i.imgur.com/udyWK0e.png

As you can see the placeholders are in the upper corner of the field on the image with the check mark. That is where I need to placeholder to move once the field is focused which the code I posted should do, but for some reason I can't get it to work with my input feilds(first name, last name, email, etc...).

Comment: Your question seems that you didn't get how to move the placeholder on top of the input. Ok so you mean to build the full form according your data and as the png. it's correct ?

Comment: I was able to use another method to get the job done. This was what I was looking for: https://i.imgur.com/mDod1Pw.gifv

Sorry for the confusion, it turns out what I'm really looking for are called "floating labels". I didn't know the term so I was finding it very difficult to find an answer with my limited ability to explain haha.

Comment: Ok changed according your request.

Answer (score 0):

firstly to edit placeholders the selector you need to use is :placeholder. The effect you are trying to recreate is really just a trick with floating the form labels, instead of the placeholder text. There is a thorough explanation available here: https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely the jsfiddle example actually is not using a placeholder but a span tag with a class of .placeholder

Your own code has input placeholder attribute and you can target it and input :focus like this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 15px;

}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-size: 5px;
}
/* Firefox < 19 */
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-size: 5px;
}
/* Firefox > 19 */
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-size: 5px;
}

/* Internet Explorer 10 */
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-size: 5px;
}
```

This will make placeholder text go smaller on input focus.

Answer (score 0):

Updated [Daebak Do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285778/6813732)'s answer after reading [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285703/how-do-i-create-permanent-placeholders-css-html#comment101066664_57285778).

I added some padding to the input, and moved the "placeholder" content inside the input (changing `top` value from `-12px` to `2px` and adding a `left: 2px`). I also added `margin-top` property to make the transition smooth and not disturb the rest of the content on your page.

Now the placeholder content is located inside the input box, like on the screenshot you shared.

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: padding-top 0.1s, margin-top 0.1s;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  font-size:25px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 3px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus ~ .placeholder{
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input:focus{
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: padding-top 0.1s, margin-top 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="placeholder">Placeholder</span>
</div>

<p>Some content.</p>
```

Comment: Wow, the amount of knowledge around here is astonishing! Thank you very much! Now I have multiple ways with slightly different styles. I ended up reformatting my HTML and got it to work. My success: https://i.imgur.com/mDod1Pw.gifv 
Thank you again... Truly amazing!

Comment: @JackJones to add to this, you can also use `required` on your input, and then use `:valid`, so that the label stays on top when the input has text in it and you click outside. See: https://jsfiddle.net/xfypqsb4/

Comment: @elveti Much appreciated! fiddled around with it a little and was able to understand what you mean. That is a very useful feature!